# Что выбрать контейнерную среду GPU или vGPU?

Tags: gpu, virtual, containers

У меня есть программа для генерации картинок и я хочу арендовать GPU для запуска этой программы. И я нашел пару сайтов: где-то GPU выдают через контейнер, где-то выдают vGPU. Возможно я что-то путаю, но на сайте мне объяснили, что vGPU и GPU, которое выдается в контейнере - разные вещи. Так что мне лучше выбрать?
Или на крайний случай можете скинуть гайд, как пользоваться облачными gpu?